# How do I access Hue Lights from outside the local network using node/python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, aws-lambda, philips-hue

Is it possible to use node/python for remote access to hue lights? All the 3rd party libraries seem to assume local access and don't address remote access.

Answer (score 0):

Philips has a Remote API (https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api/remote-api-quick-start-guide/).  To use it, you'll need to create a developer account through Philips to register and implement an OAUTH authentication flow in your application.

The commands to control lights through the remote API is identical to what you would do through your local network - you'll just send authenticated requests through the Philips cloud where they'll be routed to the home your user's home Bridge.